# XNA 3D Camera rolling

Tags: c#, xna

I'm using a camera class for XNA by [Seabase Alpha](http://seabasealpha.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/3d-camera-in-xna-with-pitch-roll-and-yaw/), and it works great, I didn't have to modify it at all. But, if I Strafe Horizontally and Yaw at the same time, it changes my roll and I can't figure out how 'lock' it in a way so that it can never roll. (similar to a first person shooter, it can only strafe, thrust, and adjust it's pitch and yaw.)

My code for calling the class is as follows:

```
        if (gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Right.X != 0)
        {
            // Look Around
            camera.Yaw(-gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Right.X);
        }
        if (gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Right.Y != 0)
        {
            // Look Around
            camera.Pitch(-gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Right.Y);
        }
        if (gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X != 0)
        {
            // Move Around
            camera.StrafeHorz(-gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X);
        }
        if (gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y != 0)
        {
            // Move Around
            camera.Thrust(gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y);
        }
        if (gamepadState.Buttons.LeftShoulder == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            camera.StrafeVert(0.2f);
        }
        if (gamepadState.Buttons.RightShoulder == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            camera.StrafeVert(-0.2f);
        }
```

I've tried forcing the Up vector in the camera class to `Vector(0, 0, 1)` and `Vector(0, 1, 0)`. Settings the Z to 1 helped a bit, but it was still able to roll.

Comment: Have you tried reordering your if statements to strafe first and perform rotations afterwards? This will lead to a single-frame lag in rotation vs strafe, but I don't guess that will affect your input assuming your game state is updating at least 20 or so times a second.

Comment: Sadly not, this still happened: http://i.imgur.com/zPFcT6F.png

Comment: [Camera3D](https://github.com/Andrusza/PiratesArr/tree/part-3/Pirates/Pirates/Copy%20of%20FirstPersonCamera) Here is my 3D camera.

Comment: I just implemented this class, and for some reason I couldn't move forward, only up/down left/right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no intention of ever implementing roll in the camera, it would be best to modify the seabase code like thus:

```
public Matrix ViewMatrix
{
    get
    {
        return Matrix.CreateLookAt(Position, Forward+Position, Vector3.Up);//changed the 3rd param from Up toVector3.Up
    }
}
```

This will inhibit the arbitrary roll you are experiencing. But will also preclude you from implementing roll too.